# Delete entry in DB if record's value == "something" using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, if-statement, model

I have a variable that I obtain through my controller. I want to check and see if there's a record with that variable's value in the DB. If there is, then delete that record. In my User model there's a 'number' attribute that's a string. Here's what the pseudo code in my controller would look like:

```
from_number = params["From"]

if @user.number == from_number
   # find a record in the DB with that value and delete it
   User.find(from_number)
   @user.destroy
else
   puts "don't delete DB record"
end
```

Can I do this in the controller or should this be done in the model? If it should be done in the model, how do I pass from_number to the model to process?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is somewhat confusing: do you want to make sure a user can only delete her/himself? Or are you testing only certain users are allowed to delete some other user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code given below, it will delete existing user in the db and call all callbacks on this instance

```
User.where(number: params["From"]).first.try(:destroy)
```

So no need to write "if else". And this code should be placed in controller only.

Comment: Thanks! This is causing a 500 error "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):" Any thoughts?

Comment: `User.where(number: params["From"]).first.destroy` : the `.where` returns an Array

Comment: You should also use the try method: `User.where(number: params["From"]).first.try(:destroy)` It will prevent from raising errors like undefined method destroy for Nil:NilClass if there is no user returned ;)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a user with a specific id if some attribute has a specific value can be done as follows.

```
User.where(value: 'something').delete_all
```

Note that this will not instantiate the model, thus it won't fire callbacks.

I'm not sure if this is what you want since you're snippet is a bit confusing since you already have the user, retrieve it again just to destroy it.